# Edit RTF, literal text in PHP

Tags: php, string, rtf

I'm creating a system that edits a .rtf file

the editing is done using plain text

I would like to put some string inside my php code to insert inside the rtf that comes from the system

```
 $ReplaceDois = "{\rtlch\fcs1 \af1\afs24
\ltrch\fcs0 \b\fs24\cf0\cgrid0\insrsid5259994\charrsid5461623 A \endash QUALIFICA'c7'c3O DAS PARTES\par}"
```

this is just an example, but I need to insert long texts like this

The problem is that php doesn't interpret literally

when i use double quotes
i have problems with

\r \f and others

when i use single quotes
I have problems with

QUALIFICA'c7'c3O

is there any way i can put my string and there is no escape in the text

the process of editing these files is a bit complicated, so I would like to be able to take the text from inside the rtf file and paste it into my code

Thank you for any help

Comment: you see `\r`, `\n` are reserved stuff to put a newline in the string - there are many more. you can use backslash if you want to write single quote within string that defined using single quote (ex. `'my \'text\' in single quote'`). the same way works for double quotes. if you want to put literal backslash you have to escape it with another backslash (``\\``).

Comment: ah i thought maybe i had a command like this from vb.net

` Dim jsScript As String = <js><![CDATA[
my string ]]></js>.Value
`

Comment: afaik, `CDATA` is part of xml not vb.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use heredoc strings :

```
$ReplaceDois = <<<'eortf'
{\rtlch\fcs1 \af1\afs24
\ltrch\fcs0 \b\fs24\cf0\cgrid0\insrsid5259994\charrsid5461623 A \endash QUALIFICA'c7'c3O DAS PARTES\par}
eortf;
```